# search form and custom query_posts by title

Tags: wordpress, search, filter

That code work only set a variable not by form.

function.php

```
<?php
function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;
if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_title' ) ) {
    $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
}
return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
?>
```

form.php

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="form_percorsi" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/percorsi/" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">
<h1>Search</h1>
<input placeholder="Cerca…" value="" id="search_them" name="search_title" title="Search for:" type="search">
</form>
```

my query for display items

```
$search_them = $_GET['search_them'];

$args = array( 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => $order_by, 'order' => $order, 'search_title' => $search_them );
```

if i search a title by form non work...

have a solution?

Comment: you question is not too clear but im assuming you have mixed up the form inputs id with the name

Comment: you have resolved mi life :)

i'm live in italy end too later for work... now!